# Looping through a Truth array in python and replacing true values with components from another array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Let's say I have a Numpy array truth array that  looks something like the following:

```
truths = [True, False, False, False, True, True]
```

and I have another array of values that looks something like:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to create a loop that will replace all the truth values in the truths array with the next number from the nums array and replace all the False values with 0.

I want to end up with something that looks like:

```
array = [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3]
```

Comment: What happens when you have more `Trues` in `truths` than numbers in `nums`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycl) from `itertools` to cycle through your `nums` list. Then just zip it with your booleans and use a ternary list comprehension.

```
from itertools import cycle  

>>> [num if boolean else 0 for boolean, num in zip(truths, cycle(nums))]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend `numpy.putmask()`. Since we're converting from type `bool` to `int64`, we need to do some conversions first.

First, initialization:

```
truths = np.array([ True, False, False, False,  True,  True])
nums = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

Then we convert and replace based on our mask (if element of `truth` is True):

```
truths = truths.astype('int64') # implicitly changes all the "False" values to 0
numpy.putmask(truths, truths, nums)
```

The end result:

```
>>> truths
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3])
```

Note that we just pass in `truths` into the "mask" argument of `numpy.putmask()`. This will simply check to see if each element of array `truths` is truthy; since we converted the array to type `int64`, it will replace only elements that are NOT 0, as required.

If we wanted to be more pedantic, or needed to replace some arbitrary value, we would need `numpy.putmask(truths, truths==<value we want to replace>, nums)` instead.

If we want to go EVEN more pedantic and not make the assumption that we can easily convert types (as we can from `bool` to `int64`), as far as I'm aware, we'd either need to make some sort of mapping to a different `numpy.array` where we could make that conversion. The way I'd personally do that is to convert my `numpy.array` into some boolean array where I can do this easy conversion, but there may be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `itertools` here as you said you want a loop.

```
from itertools import cycle, chain, repeat
import numpy as np

truths = np.array([True, False, False, False, True, True])
nums = np.array([1, 2, 3])

#you have 2 options here.
#Either repeat over nums
iter_nums = cycle(nums)
#or when nums is exhausted
#you just put default value in it's place
iter_nums = chain(nums, repeat(0))

masked = np.array([next(iter_nums) if v else v for v in truths])
print(masked)
#[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3]
```